# how can i do this jquery hover effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i already made the usual buttons but i need to make the search button on the left menu on this website 
http://www.coolwebmasters.com/

when i hover on the #profilename it disappears

```
<div id="container">
<div class="prof"><a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/profile.png" alt="Messages"/>

</a></div>
</div>
<div  id="profilename">Name</div>



$(".prof").hover(function(){
$('#profilename').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 280); 
}, function() {
    $('#profilename').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 280); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you move the mouse out of the `.prof` element, the `#profilename` is hidden.

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.prof').hover(function () {
        var $target = $('#profilename');
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
        $target.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 280);
    }, function () {
        var $target = $('#profilename');
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 280);
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $('#profilename').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 280);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TkL6t/)

In the above solution, we give a 200ms time for the user to move from `.prof` to `#profilename` element, if so we clears the timeout thus the hiding of the element is prevented.

Comment: this can't possibly be just vanilla jquery. I've tried to figure out how to slide left and right for days. is this jquery-ui?

Comment: @13ruce1337 yes jQuery UI need to be present

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can all be done with css3 transitions. Not trying to proof it with a fiddle though